# TFVC C# API refusing to download large (7GB+) files

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I'm using C# TFS API to pull changes into my workspace using a script. To be more precise, I'm using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace`, calling `Get(new ChangesetVersionSpec(<number>), GetOptions.None)`.

This has worked so far for about 15000 commits. However, I've reached a commit where, after the pull is done, a file is missing.

The file in question is a large binary file of 7.2GB. I've checked `GetStatus` that the function above returns and this is what I got:

[image: GetStatus]

Note that I tried calling `Get` twice in a row to see if it would help, the second call result is `status2`.

The changeset in question has 19 files.

I'm talking to our sysadmin to see if there is anything in server side logs, but I'm not very hopeful.

What to do here? How do I get TFS to send me the file I want? Server version is `Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2`

Comment: Could you please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help understand how you use the client library? Please **don't expose** any sensitive information like tokens/password/privacy in the demo. By the way, may I know if calling this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) in your c# project will incur the same issue?